# How we convert postman colllection to swagger API document?

Tags: postman, swagger

How we convert the postman collection to swagger API document?

What are different options without sending data on network, we can achieve this

is there any utility which can convert Postman collection to a swagger API specification file

We had a requirement to convert the postman collection with documentation and sample requests and responses into a swagger YAML file